# CryptoStream and Authenticated Encryption Modes

Tags: .net, cryptography

I'm interested in providing a managed dll for use in .Net that provides authenticated encryption services. The DLL might be used in a WPF program or an ASP application. I have a couple of questions related to Microsoft's crypto and stream models.

Authenticated encryption modes (CCM, CWC, EAX, GCM, etc) typically produce two artifacts - first is the cipher text and second is the authentication tag. Its fairly easy to stream encryption, but there can be some problems. For example, CCM cannot be streamed due to the way the header is built and authenticated encryption modes produce an authentication tag.

Decryption is trickier since it can't be streamed. Decryption can't be streamed because all the cipher text must be available, and that cipher text must be verified using the authentication tag before being decrypted.

How does one adapt an authenticated encryption mode for a block cipher so that it can be used in a `CryptoStream`? Is it even possible? Perhaps its why Microsoft does not supply it?

Does Microsoft have a recommendation? For example, break apart a large message into smaller messages or units (each with its own tag)? Or does MS recommend buffering until the entire message and tag is input?

Where does Microsoft recommend 'putting' the tag? At the beginning of the stream? At the end of the stream?

Some helpful references:

- [SymmetricAlgorithm Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.aspx)
- [CipherMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx)
- [CryptoStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 2010 the microsoft CLR security team released an [extension to the System.Security.Cryptography](http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security.Cryptography.dll) that included authenticated symmetric encryption specifically [GCM](http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security.Cryptography.AuthenticatedAesCng). Why they haven't done anything with it since then, I don't know.

But, since your question put emphasis on "what would microsoft do?", there it is... they did that.

Comment: I've seen GCM being used in both the XML encryption and latest TSL draft specifications. Adding GCM as authenticated encryption makes a lot of sense. CCM is also secure, but it is a PITA to use and implement.

Comment: @owlstead - "CCM is also secure, but it is a PITA to use and implement." Lol.... +1. I was just reading a security engineering book and it talked about the history and politics of CCM adoption. I wish I could remember what book it was.....

Answer (score 2):

You are using an assumption that does not really hold for authenticated encryption baard on stream ciphers such as GCM: that you cannot decrypt before verification. This is true for e.g. AES in CBC mode that is authenticated by a MAC when padding oracles apply. GCM mode, for instance, does not perform padding as the underlying stream cipher is CTR mode encryption. This means in turn that padding does not have to be applied, thus padding oracles do not apply.

Of course, it would be extremely unwise to perform any business logic with the decrypted data before it has been authenticated. Any code that touches unverified data should be considered high risk, and it should be statically analysed and audited. If you want to perform any business logic earlier then you should indeed make sure that it gets authenticated before do so. Splitting it up in smaller parts would certainly make sense.

Obviously these are just my recommendations. For recommendations by Microsoft: if they cannot be found using Google or (god forbid) Bing: ask Microsoft. Nobody here can talk for them.

Comment: Thanks owlstead, I stand corrected. I actually disagreed with what you said, but the GCM standard allows it. (For others: [A High-Throughput Authenticated Encryption Mode](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38D/SP-800-38D.pdf), p.2). With that said, no code under my purview practices the use-before-validating paradigm. I can switch to SSH or SSL/TLS if I want that recklessness.