# Using CBC+CFB when .NET libraries don't provide AES CTS support

Tags: .net, encryption

I think I have my head around CBC and CFB modes, and how CTS (ciphertext stealing) works.  CTS sounds perfect for my needs (encrypting variable length byte arrays all at least 16 bytes long), only problem being that for absolutely no apparent reason, .NET offers CTS in the CipherMode enum but doesn't allow me to use it with AES!!!

After much investigation, I see that CTS is "easy enough" to implement atop CBC, but wouldn't it be even easier still to process all blocks except that very last block the usual CBC way, and switch to CFB for the last block if it happens to be less than 16 bytes long?

e.g. encrypting 35 bytes :

First ciphertext block : IV is XORed with plaintext bytes 0..15 and encrypted.  This is straight CBC.

Second ciphertext block : First ciphertext block is XORed with plaintext bytes 16..31 and encrypted.  This is still straight CBC.

Third ciphertext block : Second ciphertext block is encrypted, and the three high-order bytes are XORed with plaintext bytes 32..34 and form the final ciphertext block.  This is conceptually the same as CFB mode, just used only on the very last block.

Of course, CFB mode does exactly what I want, and works, but is surprisingly slow when FeedbackSize = 8.

Specifically, loading an encrypted 70MB read-only database into memory (an operation that users frequently trigger throughout the day and have to wait until it finishes), takes 1.75 seconds in CBC mode, and 2 seconds in CFB mode with FeedbackSize = 128 (i.e. stuck with 16-byte ciphertext increments again), but takes 35 seconds in CFB mode with FeedbackSize = 8.  That's a 1500% performance penalty, and way too long for my users to sit there twiddling their thumbs!!!

You might say "hey, for such large files, the extra up-to-seven-bytes of padding is irrelevant - just use a padded mode", and maybe that's what I should do, but I seem so tantalizingly close to getting exactly what I want, which is ciphertext size = plaintext size.  CFB mode already does exactly what I want when FeedbackSize = 8 - it's just unusably slow.  CTS mode would be perfect, but for whatever absurd reason, Microsoft couldn't invest the resources to implement it?!?  And whilst I can hack together my own implementation of CTS mode based on CBC mode, surely CBC mode for all but the last block and then switching to CFS mode for the final few bytes is conceptually simpler?

Or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks all!

Comment: *"CFB mode does exactly what I want, and works, but is surprisingly slow when FeedbackSize = 8"*. I believe that's a bad choice of crypto parameters. The feedback acts as a permutation of *m-bit* values, where *m* is the block length. By using a small feedback size, you are effectively reducing cycle length to *m/8*. You should probably use a dedicated stream cipher.

Comment: *"You might say..."* - I would probably say you should use an authenticated encryption mode like CCM, GCM or EAX. That way, you get *both* confidentiality and integrity assurances. Otherwise, you're just consuming untrusted input. Related: [CryptoStream and Authenticated Encryption Modes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492460/cryptostream-and-authenticated-encryption-modes).

Comment: @jww Authenticated encryption modes are definitely nice, however, I'm _trying_ to live with just what the .NET framework comes with natively, and I'm discovering that's not much!

Comment: @jww Dedicated stream cipher also sounds nice, but again, I'm trying to stick with what's in the .NET framework natively, which again, is a lot less than I would've expected when the .NET framework is so rich in most other ways!